# Black hole and white hole symmetry

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, mass, white-holes

NB: This question comes from an idea I had while watching this video about the video game portal and its sequel (link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aj8NDOA0Sgw at 15:30 the idea of a black hole was discussed)

If large positive density creates a black hole, would large negative density (created from negative mass over a positive area) create a white hole?

Furthermore, if this is true, would the perpetual output of a white hole 'feed' the perpetual input of a black hole (assuming they are arranged in a way that the white hole spews into the black hole) so that nothing else is absorbed by the black hole?

Answer (score 1):

Negative mass is not a thing.

Also, time begins at the singularity of a white hole so there is no sense in talking about "creating a white hole" (since that would require discussion of something occuring "before" a white hole).

Comment: You mean that we haven't observed negative mass. Neither have we observed, say, axions, but that doesn't mean we can't make models of what would happen if they did exist.

Comment: Negative mass particles do not exist in ANY theory so far. There are many models describing axions so I’m very happy to assume their existence for various hypotheticals irrespective of whether they have been observed or not. I wouldn’t do the same with negative mass particles until someone can write down a theory of negative mass particles that actually makes sense.

Comment: @d_b forgot to tag you in my comment.

Comment: Okay, thank you for this discussion
I didn't realise how little theory there was on negative mass so I can see why this question is practically impossible.